# My MySQL function doesn't quite do what I want

Tags: mysql

This came from a question in Python, I thought, I could do this directly in MySQL. The guy said, the .csv file has millions of rows, so I think this came originally from a MySQL table.

I have never made a MySQL function before, so it's all a bit new.

A simple table, 3 columns: id, price and signal_

The task is, look at each price.

The first reference price is the price in row 1 and going down.

Going down, if the price has increased by 1 or more, write 1 in the column signal_

Now the price in that row is the reference price.

Or if the price has decreased by 1 or more, that price is the new reference price.
Always write 1 in column signal_ if the price has increased by 1 or more.
Always write -1 in column signal_ if the price has decreased by 1 or more.
The column signal contains 0 to begin with.

[image: excerpt from the table]

I made this function, but it doesn't get everything right. I think, maybe the scope of the variables is causing the problem. Maybe @start is a local variable in the function and another variable in MySQL

```
    DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION comparePrice(p DECIMAL)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE signalnum INT;
# @start is the first value in row 1 when we start
# if p > @start
IF  p - @start >= 1  THEN SET signalnum := 1, @start := p;
# if @start - p >= 1 p is smaller than @start by 1 or more
ELSEIF @start - p >= 1 THEN SET signalnum := -1, @start := p;
# if the change is less than 1, signalnum = 0
ELSE SET signalnum := 0, @start = p;
END IF;
RETURN signalnum;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

I looked at threads for getting the value of the next price but I couldn't make it work.

```
# initialize @start
SELECT @start := price FROM prices_up_down  WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE prices_up_down SET signal_ = comparePrice(price);
```

Maybe it will never work like this!

I will be very grateful for any advice!

EDIT: the problem is my user variable @start gets truncated, resulting in wrong values in the column signal_

Anyone know why @start is truncated??

[image]

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? A common table expression can solve the problem quite handily, but they require MySQL 8.0 or newer.

Comment: 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common table expression (cte) to get each row along with the previous value, then just update `signal` with an expression comparing the two;

```
WITH cte AS (
  -- Get id and price along with the price from the previous row (by id)
  SELECT id, price new_price, LAG(price) OVER (ORDER BY id) old_price 
  FROM prices_up_down
)
-- Join the cte with the original table since cte's aren't updatable in MySQL
UPDATE prices_up_down JOIN cte ON prices_up_down.id = cte.id
  -- Set signal to 1 if the diff in price is > 1, or -1 if it's < -1
  SET `signal` =
    CASE WHEN new_price-old_price > 1 THEN 1
         WHEN new_price-old_price < -1 THEN -1
         ELSE 0
         END;
```

[A DBfiddle to test with](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3z1NfPeshedp7aFbvRA9ch/0)

As always, if the data is important, always back up your table and test things before running updates from random people on the Internet.

Comment: OK, thanks I'll try it! I found my problem, but I don't know how to correct it: I made another column to write my user variable ATstart to. Turns out, ATstart is always truncated, which is why my function gives erroneous values for signalnum in column signal_. Still working on that! Nothing I've tried so far leaves ATstart untruncated!!

Comment: Could you please tell me what cte is? I get an error message in phpMyAdmin SQL box "unrecognized statement type near WITH". Otherwise, works perfectly and faster than my function! After I got my function to work, it took 0.0185 seconds for 100 rows. Your query took 0.0104 seconds

Comment: `cte` is just a name in this case (short for common table expression), it could just as well be `price_with_previous_price`. _Simplified_  you can see it as if the `WITH cte AS` runs the query written inside the parentheses and stores the result of the query in a temporary table called `cte`. In the queries below you can reference that table name to reuse the result, in this case for a join. Why phpmyadmin wouldn't like it I'm not sure, but it's new in MySQL 8 so it may be a version issue.

Comment: Thanks very much! I am very grateful! I was getting a warning: "assigning variables in expressions is deprecated and will not be available in the future", so it's a good thing I can now do this differently!